# Simulink: How to programmatically move all items connected to a Subsystem

Tags: matlab, simulink

I'd like to select a single Subsystem then move everything connected to it programmatically by some (x,y) amount.

If there's only one Subsystem in the window, I can select all with Ctrl-A then use the arrows or mouse to move things around. This method won't work if there are multiple Subsystems.

Is there a way to determine everything attached to the selected Subsystem and move all those without affecting unattached blocks?